# TabPageIndicator: how disable tabs selection

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

i'm tryng to block temporarily the tab seleccion, i mean, ti disable when the user clicks on a tab, so i tried with the method belows:

```
    mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mPager.setEnabled(false);
    mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    mPager.setEnabled(false);
```

..but it has no effect, Any way to do this? Thx

**EDIT**

Finally i've got it modifyng the TabPageIndicator code, controlling the onclick event with a public static boolean as below:

```
public static boolean enabled = true;
```

...

```
private final OnClickListener mTabClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        TabView tabView = (TabView)view;
        if(enabled)
        {
            final int oldSelected = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
            final int newSelected = tabView.getIndex();
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(newSelected);
            if (oldSelected == newSelected && mTabReselectedListener != null) {
                mTabReselectedListener.onTabReselected(newSelected);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

So, initially always is enabled and only when you want you can disable it changing to false